# an example of product topology

Tags: general-topology

$X=\left \{ a,b,c \right \}$, $t_x=\left \{ \emptyset,X,\left \{ a \right \} \right \}$

$Y=\left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \}$  $t_y=\left \{ \emptyset,Y,\left \{ 1 \right \},\left \{ 1,2 \right \},\left \{ 1,2,3 \right \} \right \}$

then

$$ X\times Y=\left \{ (a,1)  , (a,2),...(a,4),(b,1)... (b,4), (c,1)... (c,4)          \right \}$$

$$ t_x \times t_y= \left \{  \emptyset,\left \{ X\times Y \right \},    \left \{(a, 1) \right \},\left \{(a, 2) \right \},\left \{ (a,3) \right \}                                \right \}  $$

Is this correct?

Comment: For future readers the answer is $\{X\times Y,\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)\},\{(a,1),(a,2),(b,1),(b,2),(c,1),(c,2)\},\{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2),(b,3),(c,1),(c,2),(c,3)\},\{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(a,4)\},\{(a,1)\},\{(a,1),(a,2)\},\{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3)\}\}$

Comment: $\{X\times Y,  X\times \{a\}...   \}$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

The set $X \times Y$ is pretty close: it should consist of *ordered pairs* like $(a, 1)$ instead of sets like $\{a, 1\}$. In this case the difference is subtle, but if you had formed the set $X \times X$ it is important that $(a, b)$ is a different element from $(b, a)$, while the sets $\{a, b\}$ and $\{b, a\}$ are equal.

The topology does not work though. The elements of any topology on $X \times Y$ should consist of subsets of $X \times Y$. Almost all of the sets you have written down are not subsets of $X \times Y$: for example, $Y$ is not a subset of $X \times Y$. Similarly, $\{X, 1, 2\}$ is not a subset of $X \times Y$, because none of $X, 1, 2$ are elements of $X \times Y$.

Comment: now that i edit it is it correct?

Comment: No, it is still incorrect. I recommend you carefully review the definition of the product topology. Please do not edit your question into something different after you get a response; now my answer not longer makes sense for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the finite case, so your product topology is defined by the basis:

$\mathcal{B}_{t_x \times t_y}=\{A\times B: A\in t_x,\ B\in t_y\}$

So, build this basis and then build the topology.